# Git push to remote directory?

Tags: git, deployment, path, push, codeship

I have setup **codeship** to pull from a git repo and push to a remote site that I have setup. Things are working well, except for the fact that all of my files are being cloned into the installation root of my site - whereas I need them to be pushed into a remote directory (`/wp-content/plugins/`).

The deployment script that I have setup is as follows:

```
git remote add production git@git.wpengine.com:production/${REPO_SLUG}.git
git config --global user.email "CodeShip-Deploy-Bot@site.com"
git config --global user.name "CodeShop Deploy Bot"
git commit -m "DEPLOYMENT"
git push -f production master
```

Is there anyway that I can specify where these files are being pushed too? I am trying to avoid having to re-structure my github repository file structure.

Comment: Isn't this purely between codeship and the remote site? Aside from kicking off the process, why is Git involved?

Comment: As stated in the original post, I am pushing to a github repository - and codeship is cloning that and pushing to a remote server. You have to setup the commands to push to a remote server. The documentation is rather difficult to follow - and there isn't too many articles out there on setting things up. https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment

Comment: But why is the codeship script force-pushing back to the git repo?

Comment: Because that git repo is my server.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the push directory of the remote to be the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory, just before `${REPO_SLUG}`.

See [Git: Working With Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) for more information.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Throws a fatal error and ends the deployment.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`? (May be easiest to edit your answer in to question).